# should SQLAlchemy session.begin_nested() be committed with transaction.commit() when using pyramid_tm?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm developing a pyramid application and currently in the process of moving from sqlite to postgresql. I've found postgresql more restrictive transaction management is giving me a bad time.

I am using the pyramid_tm because I find it convenient. Most of my problems occur during my async calls. What I have is views that serve up dynamic forms. The idea is - if we got an id that corresponds to a database row we edit the existing row. Otherwise, we are adding a new guy.

```
@view_config(route_name='contact_person_form',
         renderer='../templates/ajax/contact_person_form.pt',
         permission='view',
         request_method='POST')
def contact_person_form(request):
    try:
        contact_person_id = request.params['contact_person']
        DBSession.begin_nested()
        contact_person = DBSession.query(ContactPerson).filter(ContactPerson.id == contact_person_id).one()
        transaction.commit()
    except (NoResultFound, DataError):
        DBSession.rollback()
        contact_person = ContactPerson(name='', email='', phone='')

     return dict(contact_person=contact_person)
```

I need to begin a nested transaction because otherwise my lazy request method which is registered with `config.add_request_method(get_user, 'user', reify=True)` and called when rendering my view

```
def get_user(request):
    userid = unauthenticated_userid(request)
    if userid is not None:
        user = DBSession.query(Employee).filter(Employee.id == userid).first()
        return user
```

complains that the transaction has been interrupted and the SELECT on employees will be skipped.

I have two questions:

1. Is it okay to do `transaction.commit()` on a `session.begin_nested()` nested transaction? I don't exactly where SQLAlchemy ends and pyramid_tm begins. If I try to commit the session I get an exception that says I can only commit using the transaction manager. On the other hand DBSession.rollback() works fine.
2. Does handling this like

   ```
   try:
       #do something with db
   except:
       #oops, let's do something else
   ```

make sense? I have the feeling this is 'pythonic', but I'm not sure if this underlying transaction thing calls for non-pythonic means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `transaction.commit()` in your code is committing the session and causing your `contact_person` object to be expired when you try to use it later after the commit. Similarly if your `user` object is touched on both sides of the commit you'll have problems.

As you said, if there is an exception (`NoResultFound`) then your session is now invalidated. What you're looking for is a savepoint, which transaction supports, but not directly through `begin_nested`. Rather, you can use `transaction.savepoint()` combined with `DBSession.flush()` to handle errors.

The logic here is that `flush` executes the SQL on the database, raising any errors and allowing you to rollback the savepoint. After the rollback, the session is recovered and you can go on your merry way. Nothing has been committed yet, leaving that job for pyramid_tm at the end of the request.

```
try:
    sp = transaction.savepoint()
    contact_person = DBSession.query(ContactPerson)\
        .filter(ContactPerson.id == contact_person_id)\
        .one()
    DBSession.flush()
except (NoResultFound, DataError):
    sp.rollback()
    contact_person = ContactPerson(name='', email='', phone='')

return dict(contact_person=contact_person)
```

Comment: Flush, of course! I think I was trying too many things at once and got confused. Also, I tried to work around the session expiry by initializing with `ZopeTransactionExtension(keep_session=True)` which spelled trouble. Thanks, Michael.

Comment: @Michael The 2 exceptions raised are `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound` and `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound`. Why `DataError` ?

Comment: As of SQLAlchemy 1.1 (current release in October 2017), you create savepoints with `begin_nested()` rather than `savepoint()` http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint